# How to place items in a NSScrollView

Tags: objective-c, interface-builder, nsscrollview

When I try to place objects using the Interface Builder in Xcode into a `NSScrollView`, they appear fine until runtime in the application, where they do not appear at all for some reason. I want it to be so that I can place multiple buttons and labels in the view, and have the user be able to scroll down to see more.

Am I not meant to use `NSScrollView` for this purpose?

Is there another way to go about implementing it I am not aware of?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the where you added the UI objects.

You need to consider these :

1. Is your autolayout enabled?
2. Did you flipped the view?
3. Resizing mask is working good as per your requirement.

> Am I not meant to use NSScrollView for this purpose?

No, you picked the correct control for the requirement. `NSScrollView` is indeed for same kind of use.